# How to assign a Role to a user in MVC5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In MVC4 I was using the code

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(User.Identity.Name, "Approved");
```

Is there any other way of doing the same(adding user to role "Approved") in MVC5 Identity Model?

**EDIT:** I meant to ask is this the right way of adding a user to a role? Because in a lot of examples they do not use this code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can call `AddToRole` or `AddToRoleAsync` as an instance method on any object of type `UserManager<TUser>` to achieve it in MVC 5, like below:

```
var _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_context));
UserManager.AddToRole("UserName", "UserRole");
```

For more details, take a look at the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468199(v=vs.111).aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/20/building-a-simple-todo-application-with-asp-net-identity-and-associating-users-with-todoes.aspx

Comment: Exactly what I needed, even years later.